# HBase region cannot be splitted

Tags: hbase

I am stuck with splitting some regions in HBase 2.1.3.
I see the following message when trying to split manually with the split command:

> ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.DoNotRetryRegionException:
> ecd6ce2a88f5dab5856d67640fc1cxxx is not OPEN;
> regionState={ecd6ce2a88f5dab5856d67640fc1cxxx state=SPLITTING,
> ts=1597668752713, server=xxx.cern.ch,16020,1597668462556}     at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.AbstractStateMachineTableProcedure.checkOnline(AbstractStateMachineTableProcedure.java:194)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.SplitTableRegionProcedure.(SplitTableRegionProcedure.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.AssignmentManager.createSplitProcedure(AssignmentManager.java:747)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$3.run(HMaster.java:1864)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.MasterProcedureUtil.submitProcedure(MasterProcedureUtil.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.splitRegion(HMaster.java:1856)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.splitRegion(MasterRpcServices.java:814)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:130)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:324)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:304)

In the Regionserver log I see the following:

```
<regionserver.HRegionServer>: <TRANSITION FAILED server {   host_name: "xxx.cern.ch"   port: 16020   start_code: 1597315203667 } transition {   transition_code: READY_TO_SPLIT   region_info {
    region_id: 1593698155128
    table_name {
      namespace: "test"
      qualifier: "2__20754__186111"
    }
    start_key: ""
    end_key: ""
    offline: false
    split: false
    replica_id: 0   }   region_info {
    region_id: 1597615214267
    table_name {
      namespace: "test"
      qualifier: "2__20754__186111"
    }
    start_key: ""
    end_key: "1923058__7625979394016775807__0"
    offline: false
    split: false
    replica_id: 0   }   region_info {
    region_id: 1597615214267
    table_name {
      namespace: "test"
      qualifier: "2__20754__186111"
    }
    start_key: "1923058__7625979394016775807__0"
    end_key: ""
    offline: false
    split: false
    replica_id: 0   } } : Failed transition ecd6ce2a88f5dab5856d67640fc1cxxx is not OPEN; regionState={ecd6ce2a88f5dab5856d67640fc1cxxx state=SPLITTING, ts=1597316103168, server=xxx.cern.ch,16020,1597315203667}> <ERROR> <regionserver.SplitRequest>: <Unable to ask master to split test:2__20754__186xxx,,1593698155128.ecd6ce2a88f5dab5856d67640fc1cxxx.>
```

The errors only disappear when I disable the corresponding table but it's not a solution for me. I didn't find any similar questions nor issues anywhere so far.

This happens for a few different tables. HFiles seem to not be corrupted at all.

Additionally, I see such a warning in the logs which might be not related to this issue:

```
<WARN> <compactions.CompactionProgress>: <totalCompactingKVs=102710224 less than currentCompactedKVs=588714221>
```

**Solution:**

We manage to overcome this inconsistent state by disabling globally splitting with the following command: `splitormerge_switch 'SPLIT', false`, restarting active HBase master, re-enabling splitting with `splitormerge_switch 'SPLIT', true` and splitting manually affected region with `split '<region hash>'`. We followed this process since we noticed that when splitting was triggered by HBase Master (not manually) it was ending up with NullPointerException since the state in HBase master memory was different than the one in HBase meta. In hbase:meta, it was OPEN, in memory SPLITTING.

We don't know how we ended up with this state, maybe it's a bug in the 2.1.3 version since we haven't observed it anymore in HBase 2.2.x.

Comment: If a region is already splitting, and thus is not in an OPEN state, you cannot trigger a split for it.
Were you trying to manually split a specific region, a key range or the whole table?

Comment: Hi Ashu, this region was not reported by HBase master as RIT and I think was open. I could see the region in webUI as part of the table and assigning it manually (via hbase shell) was not producing additional problems. I noticed that the issue has started when I enabled Region Normalizer on this table by adding the following flag to the existing table: NORMALIZATION_ENABLED. After removing this flag and cleaning hbase:meta for this empty region all problems disappeared.

Comment: We still face this problem. The hbase:meta is showing info:state value=OPEN.